# Cant figure out how to pass values to CSS variables from a functional component in reactjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I found a html page with flower animations in it and trying to use it in my react app but I am not able to I think I am not able to properly pass the value to the custom css variables.

In html it is done like
 `<div class="grow-ans" style="--d:4s"></div>`

in react I tried this :
`<div className="grow-ans" style={{'--d':'4s'}}></div>`
but it is not working.

I cant find anything else anywhere. Please help.

this is the code I am trying to convert into react component.
[https://github.com/jeycaarce/flowers](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

To pass values to CSS variables from a functional component in React, you're on the right track by setting the CSS variable using the style prop. However, there are a couple of things you need to keep in mind:

1. React uses camelCase for style property names. Therefore, you should use camelCase for CSS variable names as well.
2. You need to make sure that the CSS variable is used within your CSS or in a styled component for it to take effect.

in jsx use this

```
const customStyles = {
    '--d': '4s',
  };

<div className="grow-ans" style={customStyles}>
      Content
    </div>
```

in CSS try this

```
.grow-ans {
  animation: grow var(--d) linear;
}
```

Comment: Tried what you said but still not working. Please have a look if I did something wrong. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-h5Fr0o613Oeg1nXT-i8ouQAt3eIJnaE3_xDZcz61Xs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't think is an actual issue with the variable, but there is something else in you css that doesn't apply the animation. I recreated a simple case with animation: https://jsfiddle.net/x3ea6uo2/13/ It would help if you can provide CSS file.

Comment: @Zenik Here is the CSS file : https://jsfiddle.net/sahill_rawat/v6fcr495/7/

Comment: Based on your CSS file, your class grow-ans is setting style `backwards` but its not the valid prop. Take a look at my updated JS fiddle, it seems like the animation is working if you change it to `reverse` which is valid css. https://jsfiddle.net/x3ea6uo2/13

Answer (score 0):

try to use the same classNames and the same css folder into a component

Comment: I did but it is not working. Check this out : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-h5Fr0o613Oeg1nXT-i8ouQAt3eIJnaE3_xDZcz61Xs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).